# Open print dialog for report from code

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I am attempting to force open the print dialog so that all the user has to do is set the email address and press ok. I've found multiple tutorials on how to print a report to file or a printer without the print dialog, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Typically to email a report, the user displays the report, clicks the print icon in the tool bar, and then chooses email and sends it. I want to cut out the first two steps automatically.

This is one of my many attempts at doing this so far, but to no avail.

```
void emailInvoice()
{
Args                args;
ReportRun           rr;
Report              rb;
PrintJobSettings    pjs;
CustInvoiceJour     record;
;

select record where record.RecId == 5637175089;

args = new Args("SalesInvoice");
args.record(record);
args.parmEnum(PrintCopyOriginal::OriginalPrint);

// Set report run properties
rr = new ReportRun(args,'');
rr.suppressReportIsEmptyMessage(true);
rr.query().interactive(false);

// set report properties
rb = rr.report();
rb.interactive(true);

// set print job settings
pjs = rr.printJobSettings();
pjs.fileName(strfmt("C:\\Users\\gbonzo\\Desktop\\%1.pdf", record.SalesId));
pjs.fitToPage(true);
// break the report info pages using the height of the current printer's paper
pjs.virtualPageHeight(-1);


// force PDF printing
pjs.format(PrintFormat::PDF);
pjs.setTarget(PrintMedium::Mail);
pjs.viewerType(ReportOutputUserType::PDF);

// lock the print job settings so can't be changed
// X++ code int the report may try to change the destination
// to the screen for example but this does not make
// sense when running a report here
pjs.lockDestinationProperties(true);

// Initialize the report
rr.init();

rr.run();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have my doubts about: 
1) CustInvoiceJour     record;
 and 
2) args = new Args("SalesInvoice");

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to develop a RunBase standard dialog class (RunBaseBatchPrintable if you need to select the printer) that get all the dialog fields you need and from there, programatically run the report passing all the desired parameters? I'm prety sure it will work, and probably will left a cleaner code separating the report of the logic needed to the user interaction.

Read an example here:

http://waikeatng.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/using-runbasebatchprintable-class.html

Comment: I need the printer dialog so that I can send an email from there, not actually print

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the prompt() method of the ReportRun class before calling the run() method.

```
if (rr.prompt())
{
    rr.run();
}
```

The prompt() method will show the print dialog. If you want it easier for your users you could use the SysMailer class, take a look to the quickSend() method.

Comment: I just tried that and it simply displays the report when I press ok. I selected "Mail" and put in a recipient but it didn't work

Comment: Other times it throws an error "ClrObject static method invocation error."

Comment: @GregBonzo look into this to avoid the error http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/t/87818.aspx